# Unity signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 - null pointer dereference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the project I'm working on, I added an SDK related to advertising, and I did some work to remove elements that could cause loading overload in the main scene.
When tested in an Android environment, there was a problem that did not occur in Unity Editor - the black screen persists after the splash image is released. Touching the screen causes the app to stop.

The project contains advertising-related and user analysis SDK, IAP packages inside.

To determine if it was a loading problem for the main scene, we built a blank screen within the same project and ran it in the same Android environment - Successfully executed.

If the target architecture does not include VRM64, the build phase will experience problems (I think there is an SDK that works with that architecture)

I want to prevent a crash when I build it.

The project does not use Firebase.

Part of logcat history at the time of crash.

```
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH Version '2020.3.38f1 (8f5fde82e2dc)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'arm64-v8a'
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH Build fingerprint: 'samsung/t2sksx/t2s:12/SP1A.210812.016/G996NKSS3CVI3:user/release-keys'
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH Revision: '22'
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH ABI: 'arm64'
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH Timestamp: 2022-10-27 14:59:59+0900
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH pid: 26106, tid: 26240, name: Thread-50  >>> com.Company.GameName <<<
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH uid: 10511
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x70
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH Cause: null pointer dereference
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH     x0  000000005c000000  x1  0000000000000000  x2  b400007995aa0480  x3  0000007700bd7440
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH     x4  0000000000000009  x5  0000007824718af4  x6  0000007825210b98  x7  0000007825210b98
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH     x8  0000000000000070  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000007824dd6498  x11 0000000000000008
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH     x12 0000000000000000  x13 0000007824c36aa0  x14 0000007824c36b00  x15 0000000000000000
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH     x16 0000000000000001  x17 0000007b18ac9514  x18 00000077841e8000  x19 000000769038adb8
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH     x20 0000007700bd7440  x21 0000000000000000  x22 b400007995aa0480  x23 000000005c000000
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH     x24 0000007784178460  x25 0000007784173640  x26 0000007700bd7410  x27 000000769038c000
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH     x28 0000007825215000  x29 000000769038ad00
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH     sp  000000769038ac30  lr  0000007824dd6528  pc  0000007824dd656c
```

```
2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH backtrace:

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #00 pc 00000000005d656c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::GetMethodID(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, char const*, char const*)+212) (BuildId: 56e704c544e6c624201be2ab4933e853)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #01 pc 000000000031e4e0  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #02 pc 00000000003232c4  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #03 pc 000000000163e31c  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: afa59e2e094316dac0e5213eff5bdff918617fab)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #04 pc 0000000001644e20  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: afa59e2e094316dac0e5213eff5bdff918617fab)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #05 pc 00000000016458d0  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: afa59e2e094316dac0e5213eff5bdff918617fab)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #06 pc 00000000005863f8  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: afa59e2e094316dac0e5213eff5bdff918617fab)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #07 pc 0000000000693dec  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: afa59e2e094316dac0e5213eff5bdff918617fab)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #08 pc 0000000000689344  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: afa59e2e094316dac0e5213eff5bdff918617fab)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #09 pc 000000000163cf38  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: afa59e2e094316dac0e5213eff5bdff918617fab)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #10 pc 00000000016a9cd4  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: afa59e2e094316dac0e5213eff5bdff918617fab)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #11 pc 0000000000908ca0  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: afa59e2e094316dac0e5213eff5bdff918617fab)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #12 pc 00000000016acce0  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: afa59e2e094316dac0e5213eff5bdff918617fab)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #13 pc 00000000016c4dc4  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: afa59e2e094316dac0e5213eff5bdff918617fab)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #14 pc 00000000016c4d28  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: afa59e2e094316dac0e5213eff5bdff918617fab)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #15 pc 0000000001888eac  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: afa59e2e094316dac0e5213eff5bdff918617fab)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #16 pc 0000000000555454  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: afa59e2e094316dac0e5213eff5bdff918617fab)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.199 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #17 pc 0000000000693dec  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: afa59e2e094316dac0e5213eff5bdff918617fab)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #18 pc 000000000061529c  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #19 pc 000000000065db48  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #20 pc 0000000000660e50  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #21 pc 0000000000660af0  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #22 pc 000000000065f8a0  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #23 pc 000000000046b4d4  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #24 pc 000000000046b594  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #25 pc 0000000000468438  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #26 pc 00000000004682c4  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #27 pc 000000000066a454  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #28 pc 0000000000661054  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #29 pc 00000000006616f4  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #30 pc 000000000054927c  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #31 pc 000000000054ac1c  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #32 pc 000000000054aa68  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #33 pc 000000000054a9d4  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.200 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #34 pc 00000000005cd5e0  /data/app/~~NIge4SWIk5cJjPWmgJkdXw==/com.Company.GameName-Oj_JhQDNYZfXj48yJGKUsg==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (BuildId: 5c5f493179afeeb4fa912e2fb73427a60a64fd1b)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.201 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #35 pc 00000000000b3020  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+264) (BuildId: 1001969d8caf747bff324cbb95af4b2e)

2022-10-27 14:59:59.201 26106 26240 Error CRASH       #36 pc 000000000005288c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: 1001969d8caf747bff324cbb95af4b2e)
```

Thank you for reading it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case package com.unity.entities (that fixes memory leak issue on the editor) was the cause of the crash. Just removing the package fixed my problem.